# How to print messages after make done with cmake?

Tags: post, build, makefile, cmake, message

I'm trying to print messages after building process done using CMake.

I just want to inform the user after `make` command is done without any error.

How can I do it? I tried `add_custom_target()` but I cannot choose when to run.

Also, I tried `add_custom_command()`, again it doesn't give me the right result.

Any idea?

Thank you for your idea in advance.

Comment: You wish to print this message when all targets are completed...So this custom target depends on all other targets... Would it be a good idea to `add_dependencies()` ?

Comment: Yes! You're very right! But, the project consists of numerous targets. Is there any way I can get the list of all the targets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could, indeed, do the following:

```
add_custom_target( FinalMessage ALL
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E cmake_echo_color --cyan "Compilation is over!"
    COMMENT "Final Message" )
add_dependencies( FinalMessage ${ALL_TARGETS} )
```

That custom target depending on the list of all the targets you previously defined, you make sure it will be run last.

Comment: Thanks the reply. I tried just now only to fail. `${ALL_TARGETS}` was just empty. I'm using CMake 2.8.11.2. Is it implemented in CMake  above 3.0?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before with `Set(ALL_TARGETS ${ALL_TARGETS} "${LIBRARY_NAME}" PARENT_SCOPE)`. but some targets defined in subdirectories loaded by `add_subdirectory()` method don't exist in that list.

Answer (score 7):

To print a message after building a *specific target*, e. g. `make yourtarget`, you can use

```
add_custom_command(TARGET yourtarget POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E cmake_echo_color --cyan
                   "Message after yourtarget has been built.")
```

Instead of `POST_BUILD`, you could also use `PRE_BUILD` or `PRE_LINK` for other purposes, see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_command.html).

*(You specified in the comments, that you like to print a message after all targets, but the original question is less precise. So it might be of some value for people looking here.)*

Comment: Just note that with this approach, documentation states "If the target is already built, the command will not execute."

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved the issue with the help of [smarquis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3357490/smarquis).
Thank you.

Here's the step by step procedure to do it. Since my source tree are connected complicatedly with `add_subdirectory()` method, this method can be applied everyone.

1. Initialize `ALL_TARGETS` variable cached. Add the line in `CMakeLists.txt` right below the version checking command.

   ```
    Set(ALL_TARGETS "" CACHE INTERNAL "")
   ```
2. Override `Add_library()` and `Add_executable()` methods. If there's any other target, override it as well. Add the lines below at the end of `CMakeLists.txt` file.

   ```
    function(Add_library NAME)
      Set(ALL_TARGETS ${ALL_TARGETS} "${ARGN}" CACHE INTERNAL "ALL_TARGETS")
      _add_library(${NAME} ${ARGN})
    endfunction()

    function(Add_executable NAME)
      Set(ALL_TARGETS ${ALL_TARGETS} "${ARGN}" CACHE INTERNAL "ALL_TARGETS")
      _add_executable(${NAME} ${ARGN})
    endfunction()
   ```
3. Create custom target that will execute all the things you want to do after building. In this example I just print some information on screen. Add it followed by the above.

   ```
    add_custom_target(BUILD_SUCCESSFUL ALL
                      DEPENDS ${ALL_TARGETS}
                      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ""
                      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "====================="
                      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "  Compile complete!"
                      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "====================="
                      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ""
                     )
   ```
4. Tada!